# Where is my old npp+ workspace?

Tags: notepad++

Oh, I accidentally opened a "new workspace" in Notepad++.  Now my projects list is gone - how do I get it back?  Where would the project file be?

Comment: Look for `session.xml` in your `notepad++` exe directory.

Comment: But I'm looking for the workspace, not the session - that's not the same thing, I don't think.